# Arrays of SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, arrays, string

We can work with arrays of Strings,

example: String[] a = {"xx", ...}

but I can't work with arrays of SpannableStringBuilder,

example: SpannableStringBuilder[] a = new SpannableStringBuilder[10];

In this case, a[0].appends(getString(resourceId)) will result in error.

Do you think there are any way to create arrays of SpannableStringBuilder?

Thanks everybody!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh sorry,

I forgot to instantiate the objects!!

a[0] = new SpannableStringBuilder();
a[1] = new SpannableStringBuilder();
...

Thanks!!!

Joe